# How to stop 'Text' changing to 'text' automatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to run my code, but whenever I try to go to another line, the 'T' in Text gets un-capped. Here's an example:

```
Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My Text"
```

always changes to

```
Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.text = "My Text"
```

Please help and thank you.

Comment: Do you have a variable `Dim text...`?

Comment: Just write following code line, click somewhere else, and then delete this line afterwards: `Dim Text as String`. I also see that from time to time, if I accidentially used an internal name of VBA as variable.